# Are there any "Lehmer triplets" among the zeros of Riemann zeta function?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

In the set of non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function, there are some numbers that are unusually close to each other. These are called [Lehmer pairs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_pair), the first of which appears at the 6709th and 6710th zeros of the zeta function. A question that might come to mind after knowing this fact is: *are there any Lehmer triplets?* i.e. three consecutive zeros that are unusually close to each other.

I tried asking google and consulted ChatGPT without any luck. A combination of different keywords returns some results such as [this one](https://eudml.org/doc/278562) that are completely irrelevant. Maybe they do exist, but are called something else. My question(s) are:

- Have we found any set of three or more consecutive zeros that are very close to each other?
- Are there any research articles about this specific question?
- If the answer to the first question is negative, do we know that they exist or not? Does their existence violate some known results?

Comment: Most mathematicians are very convinced that the Riemann hypothesis is true whereas some (for example Littlewood) had serious doubts (also because of the Lehmer phenomenon)

Comment: Littlewood mentioned that there are closer and closer pairs. I see no reason why close triples should be impossible. But I am not at all an expert in this topic.

Comment: Better avoid ChatGPT completely.

Comment: There are but it depends on what "close" means. For example the zeros with imaginary parts, $12125271.88276506, 12125272.07355435, 12125272.2576189$ are consecutive and separated by $\approx 0.18$.